# ASP .NET MVC - Create View - labels are being truncated in production

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc

When I look at a Create View running on my PC the main form and labels are wide enough:

[image]

When the website is deployed to IIS and viewed on the same PC with the same browser everything is squished into a smaller space.   Is there some MVC project property or CSS value that should be copied from the PC to the webserver?

[image]

A few notes:

- issue occurs in Chrome and IE
- local version is run from Visual Studio (launches IE)

Comment: Could you provide the HTML markup of the label and textbox in question? I suspect your issue is related to screen size and bootstrap responsive design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using "Inspect" in Chrome from the context menu to see what styles are getting applied to the horizontal rule to change its width. For IE, I'm not totally sure since I don't have it installed, but it goes by something like "F12 Developer Tools Interface". Just guessing, but you may have bootstrap installed on one but not the other or a css file is in one environment but not the other.